# Switching themes with memorizing user choice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
const theme = document.querySelector(':root');
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.colors');



btns.forEach(function(btn){

 btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){

    const color = e.currentTarget.classList;

    if(color.contains("green")){
        theme.style.setProperty("--color", "#47A846");
    }
    else if(color.contains("grey")){
        theme.style.setProperty("--color", "#6C757D");
    }
    else{
        theme.style.setProperty("--color", "#F26B38");
    }
 });
});
```

I have a list of colors, when clicked, it changes the color of the text, hover, etc. on the site. But when you reload, or when you go to another page, the colors that I selected are not saved. It seems like it is done using **localStorage**, but I don’t understand how to implement it.
Link of site: [Click](https://xct3.netlify.app/resume.html)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing or tutorial service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.localStorage.setItem` to set the theme in `localStorage` and `window.localStorage.getItem` to get the item.  [codepen](https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/QWdEMbx?editors=1111)

> Remember to set the theme with `name` and retrieve with the same `name`.

**For Security reasons it won't show result from below code**

```js
const colorInput = document.querySelector("input");
const div = document.querySelector("div");

function changeTheme(color) {
  div.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

// Get local storage color
const color = window.localStorage.getItem("theme");
if (color) {
  changeTheme(color);
}

colorInput.addEventListener("change", e => {
  const color = e.target.value;
  changeTheme(color);
  
  // Set local storage color.
  window.localStorage.setItem('theme', color);
})
```

```css
div {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" />
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```